# How to get all the people in table 1 without getting the people who have me as parent_id in table 2?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I'm writing this post because I have a problem with my relationships on Laravel.

Here is the structure I currently have:

1st table:
- id
- name
- ...

2nd table :
- parent_id
- child_id

knowing that parent_id and child_id correspond to the same table. Here is the function that links them

```
public function relation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'person_relations', 'parent_id', 'child_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Currently I would like, for a search system, to get all the people in table 1 without getting the people who have me as parent_id in table 2.

Comment: Try, `People::whereDoesntHave('relation')->orWhereHas('relation', function($qry) use($yourId){$qry->wherePivot('parent_id', '!=', $yourId)})->get();`

Assuming the method, `relation()` is self referencing relation in `People` model.

Comment: @iamab.in `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'people' where not exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_0' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_0'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'child_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id') or exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_1' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_1'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'child_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id' and 'pivot' = parent_id))` Here is the error returned by your code.

Comment: please make sure, you have used `$qry->wherePivot('parent_id', '!=', $yourId)`. Here `$yourId` refers to the id of person you refered as `me`.

Comment: @iamab.in Yes, that's what I've got.

Comment: can you share you controller code?

Comment: @iamab.in Sure : [link](https://i.ibb.co/qxDrMfK/Capture.png)

Comment: Ok. Try this `$qry->where('id', '!=', $yourId)` instead of `$qry->wherePivot('parent_id', '!=', $yourId)`

Comment: @iamab.in `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from 'people' where not exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_0' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_0'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'child_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id') or exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_1' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_1'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'child_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id' and 'id' != 1))`

Comment: update `$qry->where('id', '!=', $yourId)` to `$qry->where('people.id', '!=', $yourId)`

Comment: @iamab.in It's now returning something to me but not the right values. When I put that id 1 is the parent of id 2 and I put that I am id 1, it still shows me id 2. But when I put that I am id 2, it returns all the ids.

Comment: Let me check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an inverse relation `parents()` to the `People` model instead of the `relation()` method in the question.

**Person Model** :

```php
public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Person', 'person_relations', 'child_id', 'parent_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

**Controller** :

```php
public function test()
{
    $myId = 1;

    $persons = \App\Models\Person::whereDoesntHave('parents')
        ->orWhereHas('parents', function($qry) use($myId){
            $qry->where('person_relations.parent_id', '!=', $myId);
        })
        ->get();
    }
```

This method will return all records which doesn't have a given `$myId` as their parent id.

Tested and working in Laravel 6.2 and 7.29

Comment: I'm using your code but laravel returned me : `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from 'people' where 'id' != 1 and not exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_0' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_0'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.''child_id') or exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_1' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_1'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.''child_id' and 'id' != 1))`

Comment: can you share  the controller code. This exact same version worked in my side.

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm using laravel 7.29 ?
Otherwise here is my controller and my model :
[model](https://i.ibb.co/tCxGFFh/model.png)
[controller](https://i.ibb.co/tzq1CSv/controller.png)

Comment: Why there is 2 single quotes before `''child_id`?

Comment: I have installed a new project with laravel version `^7.29` and my code works perfectly there too.

Comment: Try update `$qry->where('id', '!=', $myId);` with `$qry->where('people.id', '!=', $myId);`

Comment: Ok, I tried with `$qry->where('people.id', '!=', $myId);`. But if I put in the database that 1 is the parent of 2, and I write that `$myId = 1;`, it returns each child, whereas it shouldn't return 2, which is child of 1.

Comment: I have updated the the model name in my answer. It was actually `Person` not `People` please update if you have used the same.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: add `\DB::EnableQueryLog();` at the begining of the `test()` method and put a `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` after the `-get();` line

Comment: `[
  0 =>[
    "query" => "select * from 'people' where not exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_0' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_0'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'child_id') or exists (select * from 'people' as 'laravel_reserved_1' inner join 'person_relations' on 'laravel_reserved_1'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'parent_id' where 'people'.'id' = 'person_relations'.'child_id' and 'people'.'id' != ?)"
    "bindings" => [
      0 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 18.44
  ]
]`

Comment: The query generated matches my version. Please confirm your db structure [people](https://ibb.co/bR6TM5s) table, [person_relations](https://ibb.co/tJVxs6C) table. If your table has any additional field then let me know. From this data in my db, if I set `$myId = 1;` then I would get records with id [1, 4, 5 and 6]

Comment: Here is the [person_relations migration](https://i.ibb.co/ZG0vqwB/person-relations.png) and the [people migration](https://i.ibb.co/MSKYtGk/people.png)

Comment: Did you check my screenshots and output? Are you looking for that kind of output? Your ` person_relations` migration was little different from mine that's why the previous error was occured.

Comment: Yes, your example is correct, it's what i'm looking for.

Comment: So don't this code gives you the desired output? When person `2` is the child of person `1` and you set `$myId=1` does the person `2` returns?

Comment: No, When person `2` is child of person `1` and I set `$myId=1`, It return [1, 2, 3]. When I set `$myId=2;` it return [1,3] and finaly, when I set `$myId=3` it return [1,2,3]

Comment: Do you chain any other conditions with the code in my answer?

Comment: When I added the `id `column in `person_relations` table my query too not giving proper results. I have updated the answer with updated `table_name.parent_id` please check.

Comment: Oh, it look like `person_relations.parent_id` is clearing the problem !